# NoMethodError when deploying Sinatra Rack application with Passenger

Tags: sinatra, rack, passenger

I'm getting this error when I deploy my Sinatra app with Passenger and Apache:

```
Exception NoMethodError in application (undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass)
```

I can start the app with

```
ruby myapp.rb
```

or as a rack app with

```
ruby config.ru
```

and there are no problems. Any ideas why this only happens with Passenger?

Comment: You should post the full backtrace.

Comment: If you are still having this problem, show the full errors (especially including files and line numbers) so we can figure out where `#call` is being invoked on a `nil` value.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but I just had this happen for me. Turns out I needed to tell Sinatra not to "run" the app.

```
configure do
  set :run, false
  # ...
end
```

From the Sintara settings doc:

> run - if enabled, Sinatra will handle starting the web server, do not enable if using rackup or other means.

Here is a list of the [available settings](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Available%20Settings) for Sinatra

Good luck!